# Prove that $f$ integrable and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty } f(x)=0$ implies $\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{b}\int_0^b f(x)\,dx=0$

Tags: integration

> Let $f$ be integrable on any interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty } f(x)=0$. Prove that $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{1}{b}\int_0^b f(x)\,dx=0.$$

My try: I think we have to show that $\int_0^b f(x)\,dx$ is finite?

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty } f(x)=0$ implies that for there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N>b$ we have $|f(x)|<\tilde{\epsilon}$.

We want to show that there exists $M$ such that $b>M$ implies $\vert \frac{1}{b}\int_0^b f(x)\,dx\vert<\epsilon$. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Try using l'Hopital rule.

Comment: That is not allowed in my course @Rigel; and by the way why would that be useful?

Comment: Why the title different from the body? And no, we do not "want to show that  $\int_0^b f(x)\,dx$ is finite".

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @rae306 Are you user Heinz Doofenschmirtz ?

Comment: I think I understand what the OP wants to achieve. If the integral would be finite then the limit is something of the form $\lim_{b\to\infty} \frac{1}{b}h(b)$ for which $h(b)\to L$ so the whole limit goes to zero.  And therefore he/she asks the question if the integral is finite, is that what you want to say @HeinzDoofenschmirtz ?

Comment: @Shashi exactly

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz unfortunately that is not true in general, so you must change your approach!

Comment: Ah thanks! Why the downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$, given $\epsilon > 0 $ there are $c > 0$ such that if $x > c$, $|f(x)| < \epsilon /2$. Therefore, take $b > c$, we have

$$|\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^b f(x)dx | \leq \frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^b |f(x)|dx < \frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^c |f(x)|dx + \frac{1}{b}\int_{c}^b \epsilon dx = \frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^c|f(x)|dx  + \frac{(b - c)}{2b}\epsilon.$$

Because, a fist integral is finite in last inequalitie , we can take $d > 0$ such that $b> d$ implies 
$$\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^c|f(x)|dx < \epsilon/2.$$

As 
 $$\frac{(b - c)}{2b}\epsilon < \epsilon/2, $$
we have 
$$|\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^b f(x)dx | < \epsilon$$

ever that $b > c,d$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\frac{1}{b}\int_0^c |f(x)|\,dx<\varepsilon/2$, could you elaborate?

Comment: Because $\int_{0}^c |f(x)|dx$ is constant (more precisely, not depend of b) and, since $ b \to \infty$, we have that $\lim_{b \to \infty} 1/b = 0$ and therefore $\lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{b} \int_{0}^c |f(x)|dx = 0$. The affirmation follows this facts more the limit's definition.

Comment: I understand, thanks!!! @Diego